# django template white page

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

Help me 
after add my {% extends "menu.html" %>

the rest of my page is white I can not see my content anymore
[resultat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd4U6.png)

Comment: Is the `%>` a typo in your question or is that in your code? it should be a `%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

```
{% extends "menu.html" %
```

TO

```
{% extends "menu.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to wrap page which extends `menu.html`?

menu.html file

```
<html>
    <body>
        some menu code here
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

file_which_extends_menu.html

```
{% extends 'menu.html' %}
{% block content %}
    your content
{% endblock %}
```